# How do I build a static library and executable with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

To simplify the situation, lets say that there are 2 files: `core.cpp` and `main.cpp`.

`core.cpp` contains the functionality of the program and `main.cpp` contains the basic `main()` implementation.

I want Qt (using qmake and the .pro files) to

- first build `core.a` and then
- use that and `main.cpp` to build `main.exe`.

How do I set this up in the qmake file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Filesystem layout:

```
MyProject
|_ myproject.pro
|_ core
   |_ core.cpp
   |_ core.h
   |_ core.pro
|_ app
   |_ main.cpp
   |_ app.pro
```

myproject.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS = core \
          app
app.depends = core
```

core.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
HEADERS = core.h
SOURCES = core.cpp
```

app.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
LIBS += -L../core -lcore
TARGET = ../app-exe # move executable one dire up
```

Comment: Nitpick: Pressing play results in: `Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?`. How do i fix this? (It apparently is looking for the executable in the base directory)

Comment: Just move built executable one dir up with TARGET var, see updated answer

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += ../core/` should also be required in `app.pro`, right?

Comment: How to handle the case where `core.h` includes something from a particular Qt library, e.g. `QT += websockets`? We don't want `app.pro` to have to declare explicit dependencies on libraries that are only pulled in indirectly...

Answer (score 1):

If you are utilizing resources in your static library you should import them in your application as well. `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` is the way of importing a resource file into the application.

Assume that you have a resources file with file name as `myResources.qrc` in static library. Then, you should initialize this in the app as given below:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources); //Magic is here.

MainWindow w;
w.show();
a.exec();
```

The .pro file might be modified as given below for the great example given by Masci:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
HEADERS = core.h
SOURCES = core.cpp
RESOURCES += myResources.qrc
```